# How to handle horizontal pointer movements in a Component and vertical pointer movements in the parent container

Tags: codenameone

I actually asked this before but have not received a satisfactory answer - so I will try to formulate the question differently.

When a BoxLayout.X Container is nested in a BoxLayout.Y Container one can scroll both ways and after a certain threshold it sticks to vertical or horizontal movement.

What I want is the same behaviour with a Component where the Component derivative is nested in a Container using BoxLayout.Y. Both the Component derivative and the Container it is nested in should handle pointer movements - the Component the horizontal movements and the Container the vertical pointer movements - until the pointer has moved a certain distance and then it should lock to either vertical movement or horizontal movement, just like it already sort of works with nested Container components.

This would greatly enhance the user experience because out of the box with Codename One dragging for example a switch vertically does not work because it swallows all the pointer events, not only the horizontal movements but all of them.
Now - the desired behaviour described above appears hard to achieve because one cannot delegate pointer movement events to the parent Container.

Any ideas of how that could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the default scrolling functionality works when the Component `pointer`* methods are either not overridden or if the overriding methods call the super methods.

In the Codename One Switch component the vertical scrolling of a parent Container doesn’t work because it just overrides the pointer* methods of Component. See the corresponding bug in [issue 2645](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2645)

Answer (score 0):

This is implemented in several layers. One of them is:

```
protected int getDragRegionStatus(int x, int y);
```

A component can return a bias to a specific axis by overriding this method. E.g. by returning `DRAG_REGION_LIKELY_DRAG_X`.

The second bit is through the `stickyDrag` member of form which biases drag behavior to the source component.

Comment: That is no answer to my question. What I want should work with components like Switch out of the box, but it doesn’t.

Comment: What I want is handle pointer movements in both the component and its container until it can be determined what the user may want to do. The way it is now is kind of broken.